# javascript- Not outputting the result on console (level beginner)

Tags: javascript, class, object, for-in-loop

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

for (var x in languages)
{
    if(typeof(languages.x)=="string")
    {
        console.log(languages.x);
    }
}
```

Output should be- Hello!  Bonjour! Hola!
But there is nothing on the console screen. (There is no syntactical error so maybe there is some logical error) 
P.S. It's 27/30 exercise on [www.codecademy.com](http://codecademy.com) (Last chapter)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/203656